# data-centric application framework for java

Tags: java, spring, jsf, frameworks

I'm working in an web application in JSF that is intended to solve almost all bussiness logic in the DB, i.e. data validation, processing, etc, occurs mostly in Stored Procedures.
Which framework is recomended for this kind of application? I was thinking in [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) but the very same documentation reads:

> Hibernate may not be the best solution for data-centric applications that only use stored-procedures to implement the business logic in the database, it is most useful with object-oriented domain models and business logic in the Java-based middle-tier.

Hibernate's honesty is appreciated. So, I'm looking for **a framework that simplyfies managing connections and calling to the DB, and helps to write a more maintainable code**. I've read about [Spring](http://spring.io/) but I don't know if it is the best suit for this.

Also, if there is any **design pattern** to apply using just the JDBC, will be useful for me.

Any help and/or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the system architecture is DB centric, maybe you should look for DB based Web framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Spring there is [JDBC Template](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) which provides Java/JDBC integration. Here's a sample stored procedure call:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update(
    "call SUPPORT.REFRESH_ACTORS_SUMMARY(?)",
    Long.valueOf(unionId));
```

JDBC Template provides transaction management, connection management object/query mappings, SQL injection protection and some more.

See [Quick Getting Started](http://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) and [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) if you want to give Spring Data a try as it enables also [typesafe queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jdbc/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/core.querydsl.html) (sic!) with [QueryDSL](http://querydsl.com).

Comment: With spring jdbc template you don't need to deal with connection management, transaction management etc. It provide a very good and proved programming model for you. I used it in lots of projects. One of them had exact same requirement with your project. You won't regret.

Comment: I have extended the answer with several features as per your suggestion. And by low level I meant in comparison to JPA so I removed this not clear statement. I used it in one project and it wasn't bad, but we used string queries, which lead to some headaches. Also some things that come for free (like saving the entity) need to manually coded.

Answer (score 1):

When your view is more database-centric then MyBatis is a good choice:  http://blog.mybatis.org/p/products.html